# How to make sure that the folder name or folder-path is valid?

Tags: java, file

I'm working with Java 1.8. I'm trying to create a folder if not exists using this method:

```
   private void createDirIfNotExists(String dirChemin) {
        File file = new File(dirChemin);
        if (!file.exists()) {
          file.mkdirs();
        }
    }
```

This works when I give it the right path, for example this creates a folder if it doesn't exist

```
createDirIfNotExists("F:\\dir")
```

But when I write an incorrect path (or name), it didn't give me any thing *even an error*! for example :

```
createDirIfNotExists("F:\\..?§;>")
```

So I want to improve my method, so it can create the folder *if it doesn't exist* by making sure that my path is right, otherwise it should give me an error message.

Comment: Note that `mkdirs` returns `false` if it fails, you may use that value.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java regular expression to match file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489582/java-regular-expression-to-match-file-path)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Berger the return value of `mkdirs` solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

`mkdirs()` also creates **parent directories** in the path this `File` represents.

[javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) for `mkdirs()`:

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any
>   necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this
>   operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the
>   necessary parent directories.

[javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) for `mkdir()`:

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname.

**Example:**

```
File  f = new File("non_existing_dir/someDir");
System.out.println(f.mkdir());
System.out.println(f.mkdirs());
```

will yield `false` for the first [and no dir will be created], and `true` for the second, and you will have created `non_existing_dir/someDir`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820088/difference-between-mkdir-and-mkdirs-in-java-for-java-io-file/9820115#9820115

Comment: You could also use `f.exists();`